# PnP.PowerShell - Adding/importing Taxonomy / Managed Metadata to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, pnp-powershell

#### Context

I have a several old (pre-PnP.PowerShell) scripts used to query/add/update various SharePoint Online Term Sets, and want to update these to work with PnP (as well as generally improve/re-work code - remove any hard-coded values, re-structure into common functions, etc)...

However I've noticed PnP.PowerShell includes several approaches for this (I counted at least 7 cmdlets for adding taxonomy data in one way or another) - some using XML, CSV, TXT files, updating at TermSet-level, or TermGroup-level, etc. But before I spend the next 2 days re-writing all my scripts, I wanted to check the best route to go down / any routes not to go down, etc.

#### Initial Analysis

I went through each of the cmdlets offered and considered overall code design and pro's / con's (at least as far as I could see) with the anticipated approach. Below is my initial summary of the potential options...

#### Option 1: Import-PnPTermGroupFromXML + XML<-->CSV converter

The PowerShell cmdlet handles everything (so not much to do there), the majority of work will be in dynamically creating the required XML file
For general ease/ubiquity, expect to store source data in Excel/CSV, so need to build XML<-->CSV translation
... *The "Heavy-handed / Robust" option (?)*

**Pro's**:
✅ The XML is extensible and allows setting a wide (the widest?) set of options from description, to navigation links, labels, etc
✅ The XML sync's deletes, so updates are handled automatically - however at TermGroup level
✅ Use the PnP-Provisioning XML (so may have synergy with future/wider scripts - deploying whole sites, etc)

**Con's** (and potential pitfalls I see ahead):
❌ XML is not very end-user-readable, which could make updates more complicated
❌ XML<-->CSV conversion could be complex (given number of parameters that can be configured in XML)
❌ Syncing is at TermGroup level (so if only updating 1 TermSet, would need to re-process full XML for TermGroup?)
❌ As XML file is so exacting, potential for hidden errors to creep in - e.g. forget to update sourceTerm Guid, item continues to point to old/wrong item
❌ XML file is very exacting (everything is specified) so potential for hidden errors to creep in - e.g. forget to update sourceTerm Guid and so item continues to point to old/wrong item

**Summary: Not a 'bad' option, but not sure if is overall the best approach?**

---

#### Option 2: Import-PnPTermSet + 'Top-up' functionality with custom code

Use Import-PnPTermSet with .csv to do the bulk of the importing/updates, extend with where needed (e.g. if need to set additional labels, iterate through TermSet and set these)... The "Balanced" option(?)

**Pro's**:

✅ Re-uses previous file format, backwards-compatible with legacy import option through UI

✅ Sync's deletes at TermSet level (most practical)

✅ Uses .csv file (which PowerShell can readily load/edit/export). Plus, format is simple to update (incl. by non-tech users)

**Con's** (and potential pitfalls I see ahead):

❌ Are there any attributes that just can't be set via this method?

❌ May end up needing to code multiple "top-up" functions over time, which would no longer makes it the "balanced option"

❌ No re-use of PnP-Provisioning Template (so would be incompatibility/re-work needed if other script use this)

**Summary: This seems like (the most?) pragmatic option** that doesn't require generating thousands of lines of XML, or building full enumerator engine from scratch... **but are there things that this option (without the XML file) just can't do?**

---

#### Option 3: New-PnPTermTerm|Set|Group + Update Manager

Load in .csv (or other) source file, then manage iterating through the whole file/termset, adding/updating/deleting as necessary... *The "DIY / From Scratch" option(?)*

**Pro's**:

✅ (Potentially) re-uses previous file format, backwards-compatible with legacy import option through UI

✅ More control of iteration

✅ Uses .csv file (which PowerShell can readily load/edit/export). Plus, format is simple to update (incl. by non-tech users)

**Con's** (and potential pitfalls I see ahead):

❌ Not sure what explicit advantages this would offer over the other 2 approaches?

❌ (Like #2) no re-use of PnP-Provisioning Template (so would be incompatibility/re-work needed if other script use this)

❌ Anticipate code becoming quite complex by time all necessary checks are built-in (does term exist, is it the same, has it changed, get-children, have the children changed, etc, etc)

**Summary: Am guessing this is mainly used for legacy updates(?).. Feels like the most manual option, are there are key reasons why this approach is needed sometimes?**

---

#### Key Questions

1. Is there a definitive best option from the above / What is the recommended approach for adding/updating metadata using PnP.PowerShell
2. Any other considerations to note, or anything I have missed / other potential pitfalls (especially keen to hear from anyone who has made gone through the process)

**Thanks in advance!**

Note to moderator: Although this question may seem subjective/general in parts, I believe it follows the question guidelines. Ultimately, the question is around a specific purpose (i.e. using PnP.PowerShell to update taxonomy data in SharePoint Online), however Microsoft have provided multiple approaches for this, some of which may be deprecated, or otherwise not recommended, etc -- so I believe this it is prudent to ask the question about the recommended way to achieve this.